# Extending legacy C++ Windows app with WinForms

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, windows-mobile

I'm working on an legacy C++ application that runs on rugged business mobile devices made by Intermec. I need to add some functionality and would like to build it using WinForms. The idea is that users would click a button in the old app which would launch a WinForms screen. Then they do some stuff, click OK and are returned to the C++ app.

The question is, can I somehow "embed" the Winforms app inside the C++ app so that I can open a Winform as a modal dialog and pass information between the 2 applications.

Thanks very much for helping.

Cheers

Mark

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite legacy application instead?

Comment: @Andrew: rewriting an entire application just to get one dialog in WinForms seems like serious overkill to me. @Mark: What is the C++ stuff written with? Visual C++?

Comment: Yes, but may be supporting legacy + .net part integration will be more overkill if application tends to be developed further.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Andrew. Yes this is the ultimate goal but would take a long time. We are hoping to do this progressively so it would be great if the two apps can run together without too much hassle for the user.

Comment: Codeka - yes it's Visual C++ and is currently maintained using VS2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's be clear that the compact framework is *not* the full framework and therefore a lot of things that will work on the desktop are *not* going to work for you.

You really only have one option, though there are a lot of different ways to use the one option.  Since teh Compact Framework does not support EE Hosting (i.e. loading the CLR up in a native application) your only option for running managed code is to write and execute a managed application.  Period.

Now, as I said, there are options on how you go about this.  For example you could launch the application when you launch the MFC application and simply have it running without a Form, then use some form of IPC ([point to point queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446556.aspx) would probably make the most sense, but a [memory-mapped file](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ayakhnin/PermaLink,guid,abc9dafe-4199-46c7-8937-aa918311261d.aspx) might also be useful) and then have the applications "talk" top one another.  So your C++ app could send a message that says "show Form A" and when Form A closes, the managed application could send back data.

Comment: Thanks VERY much ctacke! I didn't get a chance to check out the other suggestions but I suspected that this was the case. You've saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 1):

There is [MFC and WinForms Integration Demo](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=987021bc-e575-4fe3-baa9-15aa50b0f599&displaylang=en) for VS2005. Hope it helps

Comment: Cool - thanks. I will investigate. The first question is whether this stuff is supported under Windows Mobile.

Comment: It's not supported in the CF, so don't spend too many cycles looking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that by using CCW ( COM Callable Wrapper) read more here :-
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/ComWarpperForDotNet.aspx

Comment: This will not work.  You cannot create managed COM components in the CF.